# How to fix Unexpected error occured noDeviceType("com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-12-Pro-Max")?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I try to launch a preview of a SwiftUI app in Xcode 11 but it doesn't let me although the simulator is actually there.

Simulator:

[image: Simulator there.]

The error:

[image: The error.]

I want to see the preview in Xcode of the SwiftUI app.

I have macOS 10.15 and just downloading Xcode 12 now actually because Big Sur wouldn't work on iMac late 2013.

Comment: it's worth commenting that without the simulator for iphone 12 pro max being launched, I'm not seeing it in the ▶ (start) submenu either, i have to start it manually though the file->new simulator menu on the simulator app then it appears in the play menu but the preview still doesn't work. i've just unacrhived the xcdoe 12 (after 12 hours - 2 hourz of unzip and 10 hours of me finally sleeping) so i'm hopeful x that it's gonna show me the preview there because it's kind of shit maybe the simulator is running like ios14 that's whyy oohh i bet the new xcode will fix the issue bet a pretty guine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's because the simulator you're running is running iOS 14 as you can see from the title so you **need** XCode 12.

See the title of the simulator with 14.4:

[image]

The reason why you can build and run it is because you're not connecting to it via some special SwiftUI protocol. I'm not an apple expert but it's what it is. The reason why you're seeing it in the ▶ (start) submenu is because Xcode can lookup running simulators via it's own special method (possibly by reading the /procs file)  which is separate from the SwiftUI preview stuff.

Just update to Xcode 12:

[image]

Then the preview will work. The next question is how to get rid of the white stripe at the top, I'm sure there was an article about it somewhere.

Then the preview will be there:

[image]